# Cannot Load Login Widget in Bluemix AppID

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

ViewController.swift: 
import UIKit
import BluemixAppID
import BMSCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

class delegate : AuthorizationDelegate {
    public func onAuthorizationSuccess(accessToken: AccessToken, identityToken: IdentityToken, response:Response?) {
    }

    public func onAuthorizationCanceled() {
    }

    public func onAuthorizationFailure(error: AuthorizationError) {
    }
}

@IBAction func log_in(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    AppID.sharedInstance.loginWidget?.launch(delegate: delegate())

}
```

}

AppDelegate.Swift
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

```
    // Including Bluemix App ID Information for Authentication.
    AppID.sharedInstance.initialize(tenantId: "mytenantID here ", bluemixRegion: "AppID.REGION_US_SOUTH")

    return true
}

// Bluemix Application Instance Code
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options :[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    return AppID.sharedInstance.application(application, open: url, options: options)
}
```

When the login button is clicked I can see the AppID.sharedInstance.application.... code is executed but the login widget is not loading. I see the following error and the UI going back to the login button screen again.

Error: 
[INFO] [bmssdk.AppIDRegistrationManager] ensureRegistered(callback:) in /Users/kosalan/Documents/GitHub/PS_1_FrontIOS/Pods/BluemixAppID/Source/BluemixAppID/internal/RegistrationManager.swift:36 :: Registering a new OAuth client
[ERROR] [bmssdk.AppIDRegistrationManager] ensureRegistered(callback:) in /Users/kosalan/Documents/GitHub/PS_1_FrontIOS/Pods/BluemixAppID/Source/BluemixAppID/internal/RegistrationManager.swift:39 :: Failed to register OAuth client
[ERROR] [bmssdk.AppIDRegistrationManager] launchAuthorizationUI(accessTokenString:authorizationDelegate:) in /Users/kosalan/Documents/GitHub/PS_1_FrontIOS/Pods/BluemixAppID/Source/BluemixAppID/internal/AuthorizationManager.swift:51 :: Failed to register OAuth client

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the quotation marks on the bluemixRegion, change:

bluemixRegion: "AppID.REGION_US_SOUTH"

to

bluemixRegion: AppID.REGION_US_SOUTH

```
AppDelegate.Swift func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { // Override point for customization after application launch.

// Including Bluemix App ID Information for Authentication.
AppID.sharedInstance.initialize(tenantId: "mytenantID here ", bluemixRegion: AppID.REGION_US_SOUTH)

return true
}
```